# Array or Collection Rotate in Java

Tags: java, collections

there is a builtin function for rotating Collection/Array in Java

`Collections.rotate(list,distance)`.

```
class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        Collections.rotate(list, 3);
        System.out.println(list);//[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]

    }// main
}
```

The function above rotate array in right direction. Is there any way to print array in left direction, i mean, left rotate with using this function only. (I know we can rotate it manually, i just wanna know if it's possible anyhow)?

Comment: Pass -3 instead of 3

Comment: With your example, it is difficult to know whether you rotated to the left or to the right since you rotated exactly half of the list.

Answer (score 1):

To rotate right `n` items use.

```
  Collections.rotate(list, n);
```

To rotate left, use

```
  Collections.rotate(list, -n);
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-)

> distance - the distance to rotate the list. There are no constraints on this value; it may be zero, negative, or greater than list.size().

Presumably a negative value will do what you want.

You can check with the formula described in the docs:

> After calling this method, the element at index i will be the element previously at index (i - distance) mod list.size(), for all values of i between 0 and list.size()-1, inclusive.

So if you pass `-3` as distance, then you will get "the element at `i` will be the element previously at `i + 3`" which effectively rotates the list to the left.

Comment: @rk1337 I suggest you become familiar with the Java API docs. They provide a lot of helpful information.